# CCMoveTo is not woking in Cocos2d android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am working on tetris type of game. In normal its working well. But when i press back and renters . bricks doesnt falls. That means CCMoveTo is not seems to be like working. here is my code part

```
CCMoveTo actionMove1 = CCMoveTo.action(actualDuration/divisor, CGPoint.ccp(randwidth , targetHeight));
            CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone1 = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "spriteMoveFinished");

            CCSequence actions1 = CCSequence.actions(actionMove1, actionMoveDone1);

            target.runAction(actions1);
```

and my spriteMoveFinished method

```
public void spriteMoveFinished(Object sender)
    {
        target=(CCSprite) sender;

        if(targetHeight<=(newtarget+target.getContentSize().height/2))
        {
            CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(0 , CGPoint.ccp(randwidth ,(newtarget+target.getContentSize().height/2)));
            CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "spriteMoveFinishedy");
            CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove, actionMoveDone);
            target.runAction(actions);

            arraycounter++;

            int n= Height/brick;
            targetHeight=n*brick;

            if(xpos!=position)
            {

                CCBlink u=CCBlink.action(3f, 3);
                CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone1 = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "spriteMoveFinishedx");
                CCSequence actions1 = CCSequence.actions(u, actionMoveDone1);

                target.runAction(actions1);

            }
            else
            {
                updateHeight(shape,position);
                gameLogic();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // for continuation motion of CCSprite
            if(tag==0)
            {                               
                targetHeight=targetHeight-brick;



                newtarget=positioning(shape,position);


                if(targetHeight<newtarget+target.getContentSize().height/2)
                {
                    targetHeight=(int) ( newtarget+target.getContentSize().height/2);

                }



                CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(actualDuration/divisor, CGPoint.ccp(randwidth ,targetHeight));
                CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "spriteMoveFinished");
                CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove, actionMoveDone);
                target.runAction(actions);
                tag=1;

            }

            // to stuck the CCSprite movement 
            else
            {
                CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(actualDuration/latedivisor , CGPoint.ccp(randwidth ,targetHeight));
                CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "spriteMoveFinished");
                CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove, actionMoveDone);
                target.runAction(actions);
                tag=0;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't accidentally create a new CCMoveTo action every frame? Because this will make the target not move at all.

Comment: if you have a  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause] you can't do any action, try using [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume] and after make the action

Comment: @LearnCocos2D  actually for tetris type of game you need to stauck for a moment  after every single litle movement,,,, that's why i called CCMoveto multiple times. It is running fine for the first time,,,,,, but after pressing back and then again enters it shows a static screen,,,, no piece falls

Comment: @busta117 i liked your comment,,,,,, please give this commmnet as answer i want to put a right answer for this :) THANKS ALOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you pause the game.

if you have a

> [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]

you can't do any action.

try using:

> [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume]

and after make the action